# Could not load JasperReports report from class path resource. The html postfix was added to template's name

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

I use springboot1.4 + jasperreports 6.2   in my project .I can download  rpt_monthreport_boxsales.jrxml when i start tomcat server, after 2~3 days exception will be shown and restart tomcat server system will be normally. It  confused me that where ".html" comes from?

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Could not load JasperReports report from class path resource [jasperreports/rpt_monthreport_boxsales.html.jrxml]; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [jasperreports/rpt_monthreport_boxsales.html.jrxml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

My code:

```
@Bean(name = "velocityViewResolver")
    public VelocityLayoutViewResolver velocityViewResolver(VelocityProperties properties) {
         VelocityLayoutViewResolver resolver = new VelocityLayoutViewResolver();
            properties.applyToViewResolver(resolver);
            resolver.setSuffix(".vm");
            resolver.setLayoutUrl("include/layout.vm"); 
            resolver.setOrder(1);
            return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
      JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
      resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jasperreports/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jrxml");
      resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
      resolver.setViewNames("rpt_*");
      resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
      resolver.setOrder(0);
      return resolver;
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/exportMonthReportBoxSales")
public ModelAndView exportMonthReportBoxSales(ModelMap modelMap, ModelAndView modelAndView,@RequestParam(value = "month_str", required = true)String month_str) throws Exception {
    List<MonthReport> monthReport_list = g20spaReportService.queryMonthReportBoxSales(month_str);
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(monthReport_list);
    modelMap.put("datasource", jrDataSource);
    modelMap.put("format","xls");
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("rpt_monthreport_boxsales", modelMap);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: `It confused me that where ".html" comes from?` - Looks like some part of a code add this postfix. Did you try to debug?

Comment: thanks for Alex's response.   Looks like some part of a code add this postfix. Did you try to debug?  >>>> this bug can't be reproduced in local enviroment.    and I had not added '.html' in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question by forbid the default html suffix.

```
 @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
            favorParameter(false).
            ignoreAcceptHeader(false).
            useJaf(false).
            defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
```